# How to generate functional SAS token to connect and send message to my service bus namespace queue in Azure?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

```
import urllib.parse
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import time

def get_auth_token(sb_name, queue_name, sas_name, sas_value):
    """
    Returns an authorization token dictionary 
    for making calls to Service Bus REST API.
    """
    uri = urllib.parse.quote_plus("https://{}.servicebus.windows.net/{}" \
                                  .format(sb_name, queue_name))
    sas = sas_value.encode('utf-8')
    expiry = str(int(time.time() + 10000))
    string_to_sign = (uri + '\n' + expiry).encode('utf-8')
    signed_hmac_sha256 = hmac.HMAC(sas, string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
    signature = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(signed_hmac_sha256.digest()))
    return  {"sb_name": sb_name,
             "queue_name": queue_name,
             "token":'SharedAccessSignature sr={}&sig={}&se={}&skn={}' \
                     .format(uri, signature, expiry, sas_name)
            }


sb_name = "my_service_bus"
queue_name = "my_queue"
sas_name = "shared_access_policy_name"
sas_value = "my_primary_key"

auth_token = get_auth_token(sb_name, queue_name, sas_name, sas_value)
print(auth_token["token"])
```

Code works and returns token. But when the token is used as a Bearer token in Rest api POST request it returns:

```
<Error>
    <Code>401</Code>
    <Detail>MalformedToken: Failed to parse simple web token. TrackingId:ac03ae94-ba77-46e4-a237-99cd8dc9ba83_G78, SystemTracker:whepservice.servicebus.windows.net:whepq, Timestamp:2023-04-06T15:26:53</Detail>
</Error>
```

Can You help to successfully authenticate to the service bus queue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using token as bearer token, use the obtained token as Authorization.

I have run the code provided by you and I got token as shared access signature.

I would suggest you try connecting service bus queue through postman and see if you are able to authenticate properly.

Below are steps you can follow to test authentication using postman.

- Ran the code provided by you and got token in below format,
  [image]
- Request Type: POST

Url:
Format:https://.servicebus.windows.net//messages

Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3A%2F%2F.servicebus.windows.net%2F&sig=&se=1438205742&skn=KeyName

ContentType: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8

- Use the obtained token as Authorization as shown below,
  [image]
- Try to send sample message from body as shown below,
  [image]
- Check if you are able to send the message without getting authorization error. If you are able to authorize properly through postman, then there is some issue with passing token.
- Also token you are getting is in proper format as mentioned in above.
- Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas)

Comment: Yes that works finally I got successfully authenticated via Postman as well. I needed that to use in wp webhook that doesn't support SAS Token. So finally I decided not to use service bus anyway as it seems it is not supporting Bearer token nor Api Key authentication method, but only SAS Token. Thanks a lot.